# What happens when I press Ctrl+C when e2fsck running?

Tags: centos, filesystems, kernel

What happens when I press Ctrl+C when e2fsck running ?

1. will it go to command prompt ? or
2. it will reboot & then the server again goes to fsck ?

Reason Why I want ?
I want the server to up & running, As my server was down for more than 1 day. 
[image]
Current status of my server.

Note: I understand that, We should not interrupt the running fsck but I want to make the server up & running, Later I will move to new server.

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS, When I press Ctrl+C, It takes me to the command prompt after some time. (It may be the case with other Linux)

**Additional information....**  (may be helpful for others)

My objective was to reboot the server without fsck and make the system up & running on priority, (Not bothered about file system issue).

1. I mounted the file system on rw  (mount -o rw,remount /)
2. rebooted the system without fsck on next boot. Can be done by,

   a) by editing the last param to 0 in /etc/fstab

   b) touch /fastboot

   c) shutdown -rf now

Comment: I'm glad you solved your immediate problem - and thanks for writing it up, +1 from me - but you do realise that running with a known-dirty file system very much increases the likelihood that you will lose some or all of the data on that volume unrecoverably?

Comment: Within 24 hours, I moved the complete app to the new server. Now, It is running fine without any problem. I avoided the down time. 
The fsck could take more than 1 day due to huge size of data.

Comment: I am **very** glad to hear it!